# Problems occurs when run simple_audio_recogniton.ipynb , tensorflow official example

Tags: tensorflow

I have checked sometimes but fail to find the typeerror and my mate can run this well without any edit. i feel confused.something wrong about my tensorflow version or sth else?(I'm entirely new to tensorflow, so sorry to bother you if this is a simple problem.)

the origin code as follow

```
spectrogram_ds = waveform_ds.map(
    get_spectrogram_and_label_id, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

the recall information are as follows

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-16-cccbd4885d35> in <module>
          1 spectrogram_ds = waveform_ds.map(
    ----> 2     get_spectrogram_and_label_id, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls)
       1589     else:
       1590       return ParallelMapDataset(
    -> 1591           self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
       1592 
       1593   def flat_map(self, map_func):
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, num_parallel_calls, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)
       3924         self._transformation_name(),
       3925         dataset=input_dataset,
    -> 3926         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
       3927     self._num_parallel_calls = ops.convert_to_tensor(
       3928         num_parallel_calls, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="num_parallel_calls")
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
       3145       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
       3146         # TODO(b/141462134): Switch to using garbage collection.
    -> 3147         self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
       3148 
       3149         if add_to_graph:
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2393     """Bypasses error checking when getting a graph function."""
       2394     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
    -> 2395         *args, **kwargs)
       2396     # We're returning this concrete function to someone, and they may keep a
       2397     # reference to the FuncGraph without keeping a reference to the
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2387       args, kwargs = None, None
       2388     with self._lock:
    -> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
       2390     return graph_function
       2391 
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
       2701 
       2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
    -> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
       2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
       2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
       2591             arg_names=arg_names,
       2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
    -> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
       2594         self._function_attributes,
       2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
        976                                           converted_func)
        977 
    --> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
        979 
        980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
       3138           attributes=defun_kwargs)
       3139       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
    -> 3140         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
       3141         ret = structure.to_tensor_list(self._output_structure, ret)
       3142         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
       3080         nested_args = (nested_args,)
       3081 
    -> 3082       ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
       3083       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
       3084       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack
    
    C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
        236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
    --> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
        238         else:
        239           raise
    
    TypeError: in converted code:
    
        <ipython-input-15-648b08ecf9ce>:4 get_spectrogram_and_label_id  *
            label_id = tf.argmax(label == commands)
        C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py:187 argmax_v2
            return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name=name, output_type=output_type)
        C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:848 arg_max
            name=name)
        C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py:576 _apply_op_helper
            param_name=input_name)
        C:\EducationDownload\Anaconda\envs\TF2.1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py:61 _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
            ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
    
        TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, complex64, int64, qint8, quint8, qint32, bfloat16, uint16, complex128, float16, uint32, uint64
```

Comment: Can you share the code? which you have tried, that helps to investigate your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty late but I ran into the exact same issue following the [Simple Audio Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio) example from Tensorflow. I don't really have a full explanation but it comes down to the definition of the map function:

```
def get_spectrogram_and_label_id(audio, label):
  spectrogram = get_spectrogram(audio)
  label_id = tf.argmax(label == commands)
  return spectrogram, label_id
```

It seems like `tf.argmax` is looking for input that is a number type but `label == commands` returns a `bool` type. I was able to get by this line by casting the result of the comparison to a number type:

```
label_id = tf.argmax(tf.cast(label == commands, dtype=tf.float32))
```

It "works" but I imagine the root of the problem is something different, I think it's something related to the version of tensorflow installed. In any case, leaving this workaround here in case anyone else runs into it.

EDIT: I upgraded tensorflow from 2.0.0 to 2.7.0 and this problem went away.